# Why don't you need to do target_link_libraries when using Eigen with pybind11

Tags: python, c++, cmake, pybind11

I was trying to compile this `example.cpp` from a pybind11 tutorial called `pybind11_examples` on GitHub

```cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/eigen.h>

#include <Eigen/LU>
#include <iostream>

// ----------------
// regular C++ code
// ----------------

Eigen::MatrixXd mul(const Eigen::MatrixXd &xs, double fac)
{
    std::cout << "Double" << std::endl;
    return fac*xs;
}

Eigen::MatrixXi mul(const Eigen::MatrixXi &xs, int    fac)
{
    std::cout << "Int" << std::endl;
    return fac*xs;
}

// ----------------
// Python interface
// ----------------

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(example,m)
{
  m.doc() = "pybind11 example plugin";

  // N.B. the order here is crucial, in the reversed order every "int" is converted to a "double"
  m.def("mul", py::overload_cast<const Eigen::MatrixXi &,int   >(&mul) );
  m.def("mul", py::overload_cast<const Eigen::MatrixXd &,double>(&mul) );
}
```

and the corresponding `CMakeLists.txt` file is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(example)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

find_package( PkgConfig )
pkg_check_modules( EIGEN3 REQUIRED eigen3 )
include_directories( ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

add_subdirectory(pybind11)
pybind11_add_module(example example.cpp)
```

One confusion I have is why do we not need to link `Eigen` with `example`. Is it because `Eigen` is a header-only library so `include_directories` is enough? Then what should I do for non-header-only libraries?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: IIRC Eigen is a header-only library meaning all the code is in the .h files and your project is compiling it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: To answer your question regarding what to do with non-header-only libraries:

Pybind11's `pybind11_add_module` works the same way as CMakes `add_executable` or `add_library` it defines a target (first argument) that you can then link against. In your case:

```
#Rest of the CMakeLists.txt...

pybind11_add_module(example example.cpp)

target_link_libraries(example my_library)

#Rest of the CMakeLists.txt...
```

---

As was already posted by @user253751 in the comments. Eigen is a header only library. You can see for yourself on their [homepage](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page):

> Requirements
>
> ---
>
> Eigen doesn't have any dependencies other than the C++ standard library.
>
> We use the CMake build system, but only to build the documentation and unit-tests, and to automate installation. If you just want to use Eigen, you can use the header files right away. There is no binary library to link to, and no configured header file. Eigen is a pure template library defined in the headers.

Comment: Any idea what I should do for non-header-only libraries?

Comment: @QualsPassed well you answered it yourself in the question, i.e.: use `target_link_libraries`  and link it to your executable/library. Pybind11's `pybind11_add_module` works the same way as `add_executable` or `add_library` it defines a target (first argument) that you can then link against.

Comment: So add a line below `pybind11_add_module`, like `target_link_libraries(example <library>)`? Would that mean if I do `find_package(Eigen3 3.3)` and `target_link_libraries(example Eigen3::Eigen)`, it should also be able to build? I tried it, and it does not work.

Comment: @QualsPassed You don't have to do it with Eigen as Eigen is header only. But if you would, for example - wish to link `OpenCV` then you would have to do the `target_link_libraries`. With eigen all you need to do is make the headers available, which you do by invoking this command `include_directories( ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS} )`

Comment: Yes, I get that with `Eigen` I don't need to do that, I was just using Eigen as an example.

Comment: @QualsPassed ah I misunderstood that, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

More on the `target_link_library` problem, I tried the following `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(example)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

find_package(Eigen3 3.3)

add_subdirectory(pybind11)
pybind11_add_module(example example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example Eigen3::Eigen)
```

And it gives me the following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (target_link_libraries):
  The keyword signature for target_link_libraries has already been used with
  the target "example".  All uses of target_link_libraries with a target must
  be either all-keyword or all-plain.

  The uses of the keyword signature are here:

   * pybind11/tools/pybind11Tools.cmake:179 (target_link_libraries)
   * pybind11/tools/pybind11Tools.cmake:211 (target_link_libraries)
```

This is because the two lines mentioned above are calling `target_link_libraries` as

```
179: target_link_libraries(${target_name} PRIVATE pybind11::module)
211: target_link_libraries(${target_name} PRIVATE pybind11::lto)
```

This causes an error because, as mentioned in the error message:

> all uses of `target_link_libraries` with a target must be either `all-keyword` or `all-plain`.

`all-keyword` refers to including `PRIVATE|PUBLIC|INTERFACE` in the `target_link_libraries` call as in the above two lines.

`all-plain` refers to **not including** `PRIVATE|PUBLIC|INTERFACE` in the `target_link_libraries` command, for example:

```
target_link_libraries(example Eigen3::Eigen)
```

We must pick one of the above ways to use the `target_link_libraries` command within a single `CMakeLists.txt` file. Since `pybind11` made that choice for us using a keyword call, we must also do the same. So if we use

```
target_link_libraries(example PRIVATE Eigen3::Eigen)
```

it will successfully compile. If we use `PUBLIC` instead of `PRIVATE`, it will also successfully compile.